# how to connect two Windows computers by USB for communication between their virtual serial ports?

Tags: windows, serial-port, usbserial

What is needed for the physical USB connection between two Windows computers for communication between their virtual serial ports? 
Should I use USB/serial adapters?

I am building a .NET terminal app on Windows 10 Pro computer that must use a virtual serial port for communication through a USB connection to the virtual serial COM port at a Windows 7 Pro computer that is running the terminal app on .NET.

The terminal app is the PortChat example app from [MSDN's serial port documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2).

PURPOSE:  I need to test a serial communication .NET app on Windows 10 that will eventually communicate with an embedded STM that is presently unavailable .

Answer (score 0):

You need two usb/Serial adapters and connect them to each computer.
Then connect those two serial interfaces together with a [Null Modem Cable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem).